# How can I set the type of every property in a class to a function signature in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am using a class to contain all methods related to the functionality of a class. This means that all the methods of this class need to have a specific signature I am trying to use an index signature like so:

```
interface rulesType {
    [key:string]: testFn
}
```

however when I try to use this typescript complains that " class 'rules incorrectly implements interface 'rulesType'"

```
class rules implements rulesType {
    test() {
        
    }
}
```

so sorry here is the interface for testFn:

```
type testFn = () => void
```

Why?

Comment: You need the specific key name https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#implementing-an-interface

Comment: The problem with that is that I don't know how many there are going to be.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class rules implements Record<keyof rules, ()=>void> {
    test() {
        
    }
}
```

with just `[key:string]: testFn` it is indicating that every possible string key will be a function, but your class has a finite amount of keys.

You can circularly refer to the keys of your own class in implemented interfaces, so `Record<keyof OWN_CLASS, testFn>` will be the constraining type you are looking for.

Note that in typescript a function that returns anything is assignable to a function that returns void so you won't have much help constraining return type:

```
class rules implements Record<keyof rules, ()=>void> {
    test() {
        return "not void" // doesn't error
    }
}
```

To do proper constraint so that the return type is always void you can get a little more funky:

```
type AllFuncs<Cls> = {
    [K in keyof Cls]: Cls[K] extends () => infer R
        ? R extends void
            ? testFn // if the return type is void, no problem
            : () => undefined // the return type isn't void, must be undefined.
        : testFn; // isn't a function, set constraint to function for error.
};
class rules implements AllFuncs<rules> {
    test() {
        return "now is error :)"
    }
}
```

Comment: At first this went a little over my head, but I looked up how this works and it is amazing, Thank you.